Mta account char limit
In our Multi Theft Auto server, we want to give each player permission to create one character in the account creation part. We couldn't find any errors in the code we shared. In our SQL table, "charlimit" is recorded as "1", but despite this, a player can still create a second character. What is the solution?
https://hizliresim.com/a4tmpb9
I was aiming to limit players' ability to create characters by implementing a character creation limit.

Hello and welcome to SO. Please edit your post and include the code in a properly formatted way instead of attaching it as an image or external link. Also, we'll need a MRE in order to test.

In your screenshot, there is a minus symbol before your if statement checking the character count.
-if localPlayer:getData('charlimit') <= 1 then exports.notification:create('Karakter sinıriniz dolmuş!', 'error') return end

Just remove the minus symbol before the if statement and it should fix the if statement not working.
if localPlayer:getData('charlimit') <= 1 then exports.notification:create('Karakter sinıriniz dolmuş!', 'error') return end

Since you provided a screenshot of the code I might have mistyped the above it since it's an image. Just remove the minus symbol yourself rather than copy and paste as I might get something wrong. So be sure to post your code next time.
